# how would I remove certain emojis in a discord server, with python

Tags: python, discord

Me and a few friends are setting up a virtual classroom ahead of the coronavirus school shuttings.
only problem is that people can use emojis such as the middle finger and regional indicactors to spell swear words.

How would I make it so my bot removes certain emojis?

```
import discord

token = ("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
client = discord.Client()  # starts the discord client.

@client.event
async def on_ready():  # method expected by client. This runs once when connected
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')  # notification of login.

@client.event
async def on_message(message):  # event that happens per any message.    
     # i dont know what to put here :(

client.run(token)  # recall my token was saved!
```

Comment: What specific emojis do you want to remove?

Comment: Perhaps you could use regex, and look for the unicode representations of the undesirable ones.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, **nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials**. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: :regional_indicator_a: :regional_indicator_b: :b: :regional_indicator_c: :regional_indicator_d: :regional_indicator_e: :regional_indicator_f: :regional_indicator_g: :regional_indicator_h: :regional_indicator_i: :information_source: :regional_indicator_j: :regional_indicator_k: :regional_indicator_l: :regional_indicator_m: :regional_indicator_n: :regional_indicator_o: :o2: :regional_indicator_p: :parking:

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example Cog that shows how you could gather the emojis to ban and hot to check if they are in messages. This should work for both custom and animated emojis.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Cog, command

class EmojiRemover(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.banned_emoji = set()
    def react_check(self, message):
        def check(reaction, user):
            return reaction.message.id == message.id
        return check
    @command()
    async def add_emoji(self, ctx):
        msg = await ctx.send("React with forbidden emojis")
        while True:
            reaction, user = await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=self.react_check(msg))
            self.banned_emoji.add(str(reaction.emoji))
    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        print(message.content)
        if any(e in message.content for e in self.banned_emoji):
            await message.delete()
    @command()
    async def get_emoji(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(' '.join(map(str, self.banned_emoji)))
```